# Query respect to View sql and Database Reverse Engineering

Tags: genexus

need your help. Can I make "Database Reverse Engineering" with SQL CREATE VIEW? in genexus 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible. You just need to change the property "Generate Views as Transactions" to YES before importing.

Here you have the [documentation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6627,Database%20Reverse%20Engineering%20Wizard,)

*Generate Views as Transactions:  Activating this property the user will be able to select a "key" attribute for the View in order to create a Transaction object associated to it.*